# Ubuntu failed to start

Tags: installation, boot

I have installed Ubuntu ubuntu-12.04.2 amd64 on my new laptop.  All installation went well without any problem.  Installation prompted me to restart the system and it restarted automatically.  But, on reboot, Ubuntu is not booting.  I am able to boot from the USB drive without any problem but not from the hard disk.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kiran.

Comment: What happens when you boot from the hard disk ? Try boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  The boot-repair worked very well and I see Ubuntu booting without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely UEFI related. Usually on new computers (which use UEFI instead of BIOS), when selecting the device to boot from, you should have the choice to use UEFI or non UEFI mode for the USB stick. Depending on your choice, the respective bootloader is installed during Ubuntu installation (in other words, if you choose wrong here, the system might not boot after installation). If you have this choice, use the UEFI mode - if your computer does not use UEFI, you don't have the option anyhow. If you used EFI during installation and your system doesn't boot nevertheless, check your EFI settings for an option called quick boot or similar and disable it.

If you don't get the installation to work in EFI mode , you can use BIOS emulation. To enable it, open your EFI settings and disable EFI booting, secure boot, etc. If there is a setting that let's you choose between EFI and BIOS boot mode, select BIOS.

Check also the article on the Ubuntu Wiki about UEFI (or maybe it's called EFI?)